# Javascript regex for palindrome?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

```
<code>
function palindrome(str) {
    // Good luck!
    str=str.toLowerCase();
    str=str.replace(/[^\Wa-z0-9]/gi," ");
    str=str.replace(/[.,\s]/g, '');
    str=str.replace(/\//g, "");
    str=str.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("0-0", "").replace(":-", "").replace(":","");
    var a=str.split("");
    a=a.reverse();
    a=a.join("");

    if(str===a){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

palindrome("0_0 (: /-\ :) 0-0");

</code>
```

Note  : I am trying here to remove all the special characters,spaces, and uppercase character and checking that if the passed argument is palindrome or not. I just want to know if there is a way to make the regex concise to only one line.

Comment: I think you're confused about how to actually solve the problem. Are you trying to see if any arbitrary string is the same forwards and backwards? The string you pass in doesn't contain any words, and it's not a palindrome. It's also unclear what you consider a valid character in the string. Please be as specific as you can when asking questions.

Comment: `function palindrome(str) {
        str=str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g," ");
        return str===str.split("").reverse().join("") ? true : false;
    }`

Comment: @Andy Ray I think i was specific when saying that I want to check if the passed argument is palindrome or not now when i pass that given string it will be palindrome if all other conditions are satisfied i.e. no uppercase, no special characters and no spaces i mentioned this as well in question .... next time i will try to write down whole question in here so that it is more clear, Thanks for the help though

Comment: Under those rules, with this example, you are just testing if the string `"0000"` is a palindrome. It doesn't make sense that you're lowercasing it because there are no letters. Also this will not remove uppercase letters, just convert them to lowercase. Is all that what you want? It's a strange test case because it's all just the same character.

Comment: @AndyRay under those rules i am not just testing that i am testing many other strings such as ," A man, a plan, a canal. Panama" ... and moreover this is not a test case i created it was somewhere else which i was trying to solve and did solve it but since I am fairly new to javascript i couldn't achieve a proper solution to this test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = str.toLowerCase().replace( /[^a-z0-9]/g, '' );
```

Will lowercase the string and remove all non alphanumeric characters.